# Postgres: using concatenation in the text displaed by \prompt

Tags: string, postgresql, concatenation, psql, prompt

In `psql`, is there any way to have the `\prompt` text be a concatenation of strings and variables? For example, suppose that in a file `test.sql` we have:

```
\set name table_customers
\echo :name 
\prompt CONCAT('The table ', table_customers, ' was created') answer
\echo :answer
```

The above does not work:

```
myuser=# \i /home/myuser/test.sql
table_customers
CONCAT(The table ,
psql:/home/myuser/test.sql:3: invalid variable name: "table_customers,"
:answer
```

I also tried:

```
\set name table_customers
\echo :name 
\prompt 'The table ' || table_customers || ' was created' answer
\echo :answer
```

But it also does not work:

```
myuser=# \i /home/myuser/test.sql
table_customers
The table
psql:/home/myuser/test.sql:3: invalid variable name: "||"
:answer
```

Substituting "||" with "+" gives the exact same.

What would be the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just found a working solution: just concatenate into another variable first (using simple spaces) and then pass that new variable as the `\prompt` text:

```
\set name table_customers
\echo :name
\set input 'The table ' :name ' was created.'
\prompt :input answer
\echo :answer
```